# Repository not found in git `set-url` command

Tags: git

I am trying avoid authentication every time  while push to my remote repo using this command.

```
git remote set-url origin https://<username>:<password>@github.com/https://github.com/Shamonshamonsha/<remote repo name>
```

But when i try to push to master  using `git push origin master` 
I will get the following error

```
fatal: repository `https://<username>:<password>@github.com/https://github.com/Shamonshamonsha/<remote repo name>`  not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL has `https://` in it twice. Replace

```
https://<username>:<password>@github.com/https://github.com/Shamonshamonsha/<remote repo name>
```

with

```
https://<username>:<password>@github.com/Shamonshamonsha/<remote repo name>
```

and then it should work.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest setting up SSH keys as a better approach, since that way you don't expose your password in the URL. Yes, it's over SSL so the URL is encrypted, but anywhere where you've stored that URL in text form has a plaintext copy of your password.

Comment: Double-check the spelling of your URL, then. There could be a spelling mistake.

Comment: I've double checked, but again the same:)

Comment: Just found a typo in my answer: I'd left a backtick character at the end of the `<remote repo name>` text. If you were putting a backtick on the end of your URL, remove it.

Comment: Also, verify that the URL works when you remove the `<username>:<password>` part. If it doesn't work, then you have a different problem unrelated to your username/password.

Comment: When i remove the username and password it should work,but asking username and password everytime

Comment: It "should" work, or it DOES work? If it does work when you remove the username and password, then you should use this approach instead: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: finally its worked with `git config --global credential.helper wincred` this command

Answer (score 0):

First time when you push your repo use this one:-

```
git push -u remotename url
```

Here url like this:-

```
https://github.com/usernameofgithub/reponame.git
```

Here `-u` tells git to remember the parameters, so that next time we can simply run `git push` and git will know what to do.

This command will show you, your remote name:-

```
git remote
```

If you are pushing 2nd or more than that then use this one:-

```
git push
```